# ssh only works on one direction between two Macbook

Tags: macos, ssh

I have two Macbooks. These are connected with same network, which has ip as 192.168.5.xxx.

I'm trying to connect other computer using `ssh` (`ssh USERNAME@192.168.5.xxx`) but it works only on Macbook A.

What I mean is `Macbook A` can connect `Macbook B` using ssh, but 'Macbook B' cannot connect `Macbook A`. It occurs ssh errors : `ssh connection refuse port 22`. Why does this kind of thing happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure both MacBooks have "Remote Login" enabled in the "Sharing" System Preference. You should also check to make sure your users have access to login via SSH (generally most users on Mac will be in the "administrators" group)